# Why is the console.log(errors) for React-form-hook not working on first submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react-form-hook library (version 6) and I realised that `console.log(errors)` does not log the errors on the first submit but on the subsequent submit. Does anyone know why this is happening?
This is a codesandbox I forked and updated based on the issue I am facing; https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-errors-validatecriteriamode-all-forked-p3xft?file=/src/index.js

Any help will be appreciated!

More information:
I am making a 3 part (expandable) form (ie part 1 will open, part 2 and 3 are closed based on which part the user clicks on), and there is only one submit button. I have wrapped all the parts in a form and the errors seems to be working as I added a styling something like `errors.name && <>required!</>`. However, since they are expandable parts, I would like to open the part that contains the error.
I tried if(errors.name) open part 1, but it did not work on the first submit. It only works on the second submit.
I tried to console log the error after this line `errors.name && <>required!</>`, and the error will show up, but it does not show up when I do the same in the submit method. I'm not too sure how I should go about resolving this issue. Please help! :(